# Highlighting search results do not work in some situation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am very new in Javascript.

I want to make some basic stuffs that can be used in my future project.

One of the stuffs I need is highlighting some keywords.

http://jsfiddle.net/4wMjP/1/

You can find the working code for the functionality at the above link.

The problem is if I uncomment the following line in HTML,

```
<!-- <h1>Polls show Romney surging ahead of Gingrich in Florida</h1> -->
```

The functionality does not work.

What is the problem and how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have block level elements inside a paragraph tag.

```
<p><h1></h1></p> <!-- Not valid HTML! -->
```

If you want the heading to be inside the `<p>` and searchable then change the `<p>` to a `<div>`

http://jsfiddle.net/4wMjP/2/

Comment: And the browser turns that bad HTML into `<p class="article"></p><h1>...</h1><p>...</p>` so he ends up searching an empty `<p>`.

Comment: Ahh, that was the problem. I should have to study XHTML first. Thank you for the answer!